# How to get and display database table value in codeigniter error was coming

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a new codeigniter developer and have encountered an error. I have stored some value in database and want to display it in view page. Help me please.

**Controller**

```
function get_user_value()  {
$data['query'] = $this->user_m->user_data_set($query);
$this->load->view('user_settings', $data);  }
```

**Model**

```
  public function user_details()
{
// $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('user')->get();
 $query = $this->db->get('user');
   return $query->$result();
}
```

Comment: plz separate your controller code and model code

Comment: Please show `user_data_set($query)` this model function too

Comment: what error you got and have to load your model in controller file?

Comment: Load your model in your controller $this->load->model('user_m'). Also please post the error.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: query

Comment: because you not define $query in your get_user_value() controller function

Comment: 1) From where do you get `$query` within controller 2) You were calling `user_data_set` function of model `user_m` and showing `user_details` function of model 3) You have typo within your code in model function `return $query->$result();` it should be `return $query->result();` and if you want an array it should be like `return $query->result_array();` @venkateshA

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Note call first the model to your controller
add first this function _construct()

```
function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model("model_file_name", "model_name_alias");
        //Example $this->load->model("user_model","user");
        //the "user_model" is the file name in your model folder 
}

function get_user_value()  {
  $data['query'] = $this->model_name_alias->user_details();
  $this->load->view('user_settings', $data);  
}
```